# Webclient DownloadFileAsync is way slower than downloading same file from Browser

Tags: c#, webclient

So I wrote a program which downloads mp3 files from a website. They are about 17mb and if I download them using my browser, each file takes 2 seconds. However using webClient.DownloadFileAsync each file takes roughly 2 minutes. I don't know how I can fix this; I tried changing the webClient Proxy setting, but without any success.

This is my code

```
List<string> links = new List<string> { };


WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(links[counter - 1]), @"downloads\" + removeInvalid + @"\" + removeInvalid + " " + counter + ".mp3");
client.Dispose();
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated :)

Comment: Same machine? A lot a possible variables. A lot of missing info.

Answer (score 0):

I know that its too late, but for me helped set proxy to:

```
webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

Setting proxy to null also didnt helped for me